# I can't sign in to my account

Tags: bug

I have a problem on https://physics.stackexchange.com. I am trying to log into [this account](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/225124/george-cowley?newreg=5fac5c5ee5a64c559cf1710139b67cc3), but trying to results in me creating a new account. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried using the account recovery link to reset your password? I know I sometimes forget which email address I have used to access my account and so that has helped me sort out problems in the past.

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: When you click on the "Log In" button, it prompts you for an email and a password. Between the two entry boxes, there is a "Forgot password" link. You can also [click here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery).

Comment: I don't see the log in button. It Signed me into another account.

Comment: I may have used nonsense credentials for it.